# Display date/time remaining current time

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin

I am trying to create a function to send me back a String which represent a restaurant opening status like: "Open", "Closed", "22min"

I have the closing time displayed as: `2021-05-11T06:45:00Z`

I would like to make a comparison based on current time, but it's not working.

I have done the code below:

```
fun getCloseTime(ctx: Context): String? {
    val timeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val diff: Duration = Duration.between(
            LocalTime.parse(next_close_time, timeFormatter),
            LocalTime.parse(getISO8601StringForDate(), timeFormatter))
    return when {
        (diff.toDays().toInt() > 0 ) || (diff.toHours() > 0) -> "Open"
        (diff.toMinutes().toInt() <= 60) -> diff.toMinutes().toString()
        else -> ctx.getString(R.string.closed)
    }
}

private fun getISO8601StringForDate(): String? {
    val now = Date()
    val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    return dateFormat.format(now)
}
```

My goal is to:

- return "Closed" when current is after the `next_close_time`
- when the diff between `next_close_time` and `current` is more than an hour, we display "Open"
- - when the diff between `next_close_time` and `current` is less than an hour, we display the remain time in minute before closure

Any idea?

Comment: In what way not working? Please give one or more examples of unexpected return value or error message that you get. PS Maybe use `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`?

Comment: Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, (which we can since Java 6) I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` too. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. You can get all the functionality you need from java.time.

Answer (score 1):

Not only are there bugs in your code, but there are also some opportunities for simplification.

- **Bug:** Your duration has the wrong sign. You are calculating the duration *from* the closing time *to* the current time, so it will be positive if we closed a while ago and negative if closing happens later. I believe you intended the opposite. So swap the two arguments to `Duration.between()`.
- **Bug and opportunity for simplification:** `getISO8601StringForDate()` returns the wrong format for your parsing. When I ran your code, I got an exception like `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-05-11T13:27:20Z' could not be parsed at index 2` because the quoted string doesn’t match your format pattern of `hh:mm a`. There’s no reason to format the current time in UTC just to parse it back. Instead just get the current time in UTC from `LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` and don’t use `getISO8601StringForDate()` at all.
- **Opportunity for simplification:** If `diff.toDays().toInt() > 0` is `true`, then `diff.toHours() > 0` necessarily also is, so you need only the latter condition.
- **Bug:** If we didn’t go into the first case where the duration was at least one full hour, then `diff.toMinutes().toInt() <= 60` will *always*  be `true`. Instead what you need to test at this point is whether `diff` is positive (greater than 0). You may use `not(diff.isNegative())` (if I have understood Kotlin `not()` correctly).

PS As I said in this context you don’t need the current point in time in UTC in ISO 8601 format. If some day someone needs that, the way to obtain it is simple:

```
    return Instant.now().toString()
```

This returns a string like `2021-05-13T04:02:04.267Z`, which is fine since the fraction of second is optional according to the ISO 8601 standard.

Link: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).